# Get the currently active span from implicit context

Tags: open-telemetry

I found this in [opentelemetry/specification/trace/api](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/master/specification/trace/api.md):

> If the language has support for implicitly propagated `Context` (see [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/master/specification/context/context.md#optional-global-operations)), the API SHOULD also provide the following functionality:
>
> - Get the currently active span from the implicit context. This is equivalent to getting the implicit context, then extracting the `Span` from the context.
> - Set the currently active span to the implicit context. This is equivalent to getting the implicit context, then inserting the `Span` to the context.

But I didn't find the method to get the currently active span in java or go. Is there any language that support this feature? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, .NET supports it: `global::OpenTelemetry.Trace.Tracer.CurrentSpan`. This works, because there can be only one 'active' span in any given execution flow at a time. To be clear: there can be more than one span concurrently active, just not in the same execution flow; execution flows can fork, but each fork has only one active span at a time.

Also, .NET already has the equivalent of the OpenTelemetry API in its Activity API.

- Tracer is a wrapper around ActivitySource.
- TelemetrySpan is a wrapper around Activity.

You can also get the current `System.Diagnostics.ActivityContext` by accessing `Activity.Current.Context`.

The OpenTelemetry API's .NET reference implementation recommends that you just use the .NET framework's built-in Activity API directly. However, it also provides OpenTelemetry shims that wrap the Activity API.

For example, you can implicitly convert an `OpenTelemetry.Trace.SpanContext` to a `System.Diagnostics.ActivityContext`. And you can convert it back with `new OpenTelemetry.Trace.SpanContext(activityContext)`.

I don't see a method to get a TelemetrySpan from a SpanContext; however. So `global::OpenTelemetry.Trace.Tracer.CurrentSpan` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Current span in Java is simply `Span.current()`.

This code snippet creates a child span of the current span:

```
Span childSpan = tracer.spanBuilder("This is a child span")
                        .setParent(Context.current().with(Span.current()))
                        .startSpan();
```